# How to spawn a perfectly silent daemon in ZSH which would last only for the session?

Tags: terminal, zsh, process, forking

This question is quite similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1228411/silent-background-jobs-in-zsh), although it's a bit more constrained. I would like to start a background job, but:

- I don't want any `[1] 769021` to be printed.
- I don't want **only this particular process** to cause warnings like `zsh: you have running jobs.`
- I don't want to see `[1]  + done       myprocess` when the process is started/terminated.
- I don't want to let it block my script from executing.
- I want it to be killed when the hosting ZSH terminates.

I don't mind if it's listed under `jobs` or whatever explicit query I make.

I tried several different tricks with `( myprocess & )`, `setopt`, wrapping in a function, redirecting outputs, but none fulfilled all points. Is that even possible?

---

What I am really doing: I want to start a new `emacs` daemon for every single ZSH session, but I don't want it to disturb or slow down my workflow.